# Laravel logout, hittin gthe back button send s me back into the app, how do I prevent this

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization

Currently I use the default laravel login/auth controllers, routes, views and no custom logic. We are building an app where if you logout and click the back button you cannot, under any circumstance "be taken back into the app, even if you have no session."

Is there a way to have the back button when clicked after you logout, not send you back into the app? Like we cant show anything once you click the back button. It should got to a laravel error screen or auto send you back to login.

All of my controllers do have `$this->middleware('auth');` which should auto resend you back to the login screen.

Comment: You need to prevent the browser cache (for the page(s) that needs to be kept private) and/or remove the history. Clearing the history can only be done from javascript so would mean sending some code with the logout confirmation page

Comment: @Snapey Can you give a proper answer with an example solution so I can A mark it as accepted and B understand what you are talking about? This sounds like the right example.

Comment: After some experiments, its possible to redirect the user to a 'logged out' page, and on this page, replace the last item in the history with the same page. It does not seem possible to remove earlier entries in the history, so whilst the user cannot press back, they can hold down the back button and select any of the previous pages.

Comment: @Snapey most of our clients are not that tech savvy to hold down the back button to select a page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to prevent the back button being used, and don't actually care that the user can hold the back button and go to earlier pages, then the following disables the back button.

(of course you can use both disable cache and disable back button)

### Create a new 'Logged out' view

This is optional but means you can add the javascript without worrying about affecting any other functionality.

```
@extends('layouts.app',[$title='Logout | '])

@section('content')
<div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
        <div class="w-full max-w-md">

            <h1 class="text-2xl text-gray-700 text-center">You have been successfully logged out</h1>

            <p class='mt-8 text-xl text-indigo-800 text-center underline'><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login?</a></p>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                history.pushState(null, null, `{{ route('logout') }}`);
                window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
                    history.pushState(null, null, `{{ route('logout') }}`);
                });
            </script>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

### Create a route to display the logout page

```
Route::view('/logout','auth.logout')->name('logout');
```

### Modify the login controller to go to the Logout view

Add the following code somewhere inside `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

```
    private function loggedOut($request)
    {
        return redirect(route('logout'));
    }
```

Comment: On Safari, I can long-press on the History-Back-Button and then gain access to the different views I visited. I can then still re-visit pages although I'm logged out.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of testing, I've found that the only solution is to force a no-store header on the response of all 'secure' pages so that the browser should not cache it.  On slow networks this might add a small delay to page loading. It only affects the returned response, none of the assets loaded by the page are affected. They still can be cached.

Create a new middleware with `php artisan make:middleware NoCacheHeaders`

Edit as suggested below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class NoCacheHeaders
{
    /**
     * Add set no caching HTTP headers.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|array  $options
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $options = [])
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->header('Expires', 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
        $response->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store, max-age=0, private');

        return $response;
    }

}
```

Add this middleware to `\App\Http\Kernel.php` in the `routeMiddleware` section

```
        'nocache' => \App\Http\Middleware\NoCacheHeaders::class,
```

middleware `nocache` can now be added to groups or individual routes.  I add to all the routes protected with `auth`

```
//protected routes (must be logged in)
Route::middleware(['auth','nocache'])->group(function(){

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    Route::name('admin.')->group(function () {
        Route::resource('admin/users','Admin\UserController');
        Route::resource('admin/roles','Admin\RoleController');
    });

});
```

Now, after viewing the protected pages, logging out and returning back, the previous pages are not revealed.

Comment: There comes a problem with this solution on current macOS Safari. If you close the tab and then restore then (CMD+Z "Undo close tab"), the login form is being shown although the user is logged in. This is because Safari does not send any cookies when restoring the tab, hence Laravel thinks there is no active session.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily route all traffic through auth middleware in the route class using route group :

```
Auth::routes(); // exclude auth route from being guarded

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    // add all your routes here
   Route::get('/',function (){
          return view('welcome);
   });
});
```

Edit 1:
To prevent user from using cached version please give look on this article
 https://twitteinfo.com/laravel-5-how-to-prevent-browser-back-button-after-user-logout/

Comment: Why doesn’t having the $this->middleware(‘auth’) in all controllers do that automatically?

Comment: both ways are good and result the same, but diff in when validation happens in the request lifecycle. before loading controller (in route), while loading controller ( in the constructor). both will redirect to login if user tried to access the route

Comment: Unfortunately does not stop the browser from just showing the content from its cache, with no reference to the server.

Comment: I think this article will be helpful https://twitteinfo.com/laravel-5-how-to-prevent-browser-back-button-after-user-logout/